# How to add horizontal scrollbar to datatable using css instead of datatable plugin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem on the datatable width to allow overflow-x to scrollable. I want to fix the column width and not allow to resize the width, show the scroll bar if exceed the width.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap display" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:30%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:30%;">Position</th>
            <th style="width:30%;">Office</th>
            <th style="width:30%;">Age</th>
            <th style="width:30%;">Start date</th>
            <th style="width:30%;">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>       
</table>
```

I want the table to be displayed with fixed width for each of column without adjust automatically. Add horizontal scrollbar to allow content scrollable without change of its width.

Set scrollX true in datatable will affect header alignment so i am not using it.Any solution i can make it using css?

Comment: this may help: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '%' to 'px'.

eg: `width:100px;`